# Why the poll queue is not empty , and the event loop enters check phase

Tags: node.js, event-loop

```
    fs.readFile('./1.js', (err, data) => {
        console.log('starta');
        setTimeout(() => console.log('settimeouta'), 20);
        const now = new Date();
        while (new Date() - now < 1000) {
            
        }
        console.log('before setIa')
        setImmediate(() => {console.log('setImmediatea')})
    });
    fs.readFile('./1.js', (err, data) => {
        console.log('startb');
        setTimeout(() => console.log('settimeoutb'), 20);
        const now = new Date();
        while (new Date() - now < 1000) {

        }
        console.log('before setIb')
        setImmediate(() => {console.log('setImmediateb')})
    });
    fs.readFile('./1.js', (err, data) => {
        console.log('startc');
        setTimeout(() => console.log('settimeoutc'), 20);
        const now = new Date();
        while (new Date() - now < 1000) {
            
        }
        console.log('before setIc')
        setImmediate(() => {console.log('setImmediatec')})
    });
```

`1.js` is so small that the all I/O callbacks has enough time to enter the poll queue; but the results is not meet expectations，please tell me why and the poll detection order and priority.

My expectation is the all I/O callbacks first call; then all the setImmediate call, last the setTimeout, like:

- starta;
- before setIa;
- startb;
- before setIb;
- startc;
- before setIc;
- setImmediatea;
- setImmediateb;
- setImmediatec;
- settimeouta;
- settimeoutb;
- settimeoutc;

but the result may be like:

- starta;
- before setIa;
- setImmediatea;
- settimeouta;
- startc;
- before setIc;
- setImmediatec;
- settimeoutc;
- startb;
- before setIb;
- setImmediateb;
- settimeoutb;

Comment: What result? What expectations? But for starters `while (new Date() - now < 1000) { }` is blocking your main thread once reached

Comment: My expectation is the all I/O callbacks first call; then all the setImmediate call, last the setTimeout, like:
starta;
before setIa;
startb;
before setIb;
startc;
before setIc;
setImmediatea;
setImmediateb;
setImmediatec;
settimeouta;
settimeoutb;
settimeoutc;
but the result may be like:
starta;
before setIa;
setImmediatea;
settimeouta;
startc;
before setIc;
setImmediatec;
settimeoutc;
startb;
before setIb;
setImmediateb;
settimeoutb;

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.